# How to find the maximum peak of $\phi$ on $[0,l]$.

Tags: calculus

You are given, $\phi(r)=a_1J_0(\alpha r)+a_2J_0(\beta r)$, where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are constants so that $a_1+a_2=1$, and $r\in[0,\infty)$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parameters, which are positive. If there is some $l>0$ such that $\phi(l)=0$ and $\phi$ is non negative on $[0,l]$. **How to find the maximum peak of $\phi$ on $[0,l]$.**
Here $J_0$ denotes the Bessel function of the first kind.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the maximum occurs at a critical point.  We want to solve
$$ \phi'(r) = -\alpha a_1 J_1(\alpha r) - \beta a_2 J_1(\beta r) = 0$$
for $r$, which will generally have to be done numerically.

Comment: But $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive parameters, How to sort out that problem

Comment: @DilrukGallage First step could be substituting $a_2 = 1 - a_1$ to get rid of one variable.